# How to solve TypeError: catalogs.map is not a function in react.js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Am a newbie in react, so pardon me if am unable to fully explain the problem am facing, but after google searching, I came to understand that the object am trying to map is not an array(which am not sure is the case this time around because, all the examples I see online is the same and I take my time for the past 4weeks to diligently follow up the examples I see online but I cant just figure my react app to work

In

> catalog.js

(this is the react component script, located in the component folder), I have this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

import * as catalogActions from "../../actions/catalog";

import ProductImage from "./ProductImage";
import ProductThumbs from "./ProductThumbs";

export class CatalogComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchCatalog();
  }
  render() {
    const { catalogs, selectProduct, selectedProduct } = this.props;
    return (
      //let { catalogs } = this.props;
      <div>
        <h1>Catalog Field</h1>
        <div className="image-gallery" hidden={!selectedProduct}>
          <ProductImage product={selectedProduct} />
          <ProductThumbs selectProduct={selectProduct} catalogs={catalogs} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    catalogs: state.catalogs,
    selectedProduct: state.selectedProduct
  }),
  dispatch => bindActionCreators(catalogActions, dispatch)
)(CatalogComponent);
```

And in

> productImage.js

I have this

```
import React from “react”;

export default function ProductImage({ product }) {
  return (
    <div className="gallery-image">
      <div>{product ? <img src={product} alt={"gbenga"} /> : null}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And

> productThumbs.js

has this

import React from "react";

```
export default function ProductThumbs({ catalogs, selectProduct }) {
  return (
    <div className="image-scroller">
      {catalogs.map((product, index) => (
        <div key={index} onClick={selectProduct.bind(this, product)}>
          <img src={product} alt={"gbenga now"} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem is in this script as it says

> catalogs.map is not a function

this is what is in the reducer

```
import { CATALOGS_RECEIVED } from "../constants/catalog";
import { SELECT_PRODUCT } from "../constants/catalog";

    export default function catalogs(state = { catalogs: [] }, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case CATALOGS_RECEIVED:
          console.log(JSON.stringify(action.catalogs));
          return { ...state, catalogs: action.catalogs };
        case SELECT_PRODUCT:
          return { ...state, selectedProduct: action.product };
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

I don't think the problem has anything to do with

> sagas

Comment: do ```{ Array.isArray(catalogs) && catalogs.map...``` to see if the error goes away.

Comment: inside productThumbs.js?

Comment: yes inside ```productThumbs.js.js``` where you are using map

Comment: What's the content of `catalogs`?

Comment: @Junius, the error is gone but nothing display except the <h1>tags content</h1>

Comment: @curiousdev the contents of catalogs include, the product photo, title, description, price and id

Comment: just before the ```return``` in ```productThumbs.js.js``` add ```console.log(catalogs)```

Comment: @JuniusL.It returns an empty array. I actually initialize it to an empty array in the reducer

Comment: try supplying it with a default value and see if it will be display